# Adding a select all shortcut (Ctrl + A) to a .net listview?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, keyboard-shortcuts

Like the subject says I have a listview, and I wanted to add the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> select all shortcut to it.  My first problem is that I can't figure out how to programmatically select all items in a listview.  It seems like it should be relatively easy, like `ListView.SelectAll()` or `ListView.Items.SelectAll()`, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  My next problem is how to define the keyboard shortcut for the `ListView`.  Do I do it in a `KeyUp` event, but then how would you check two presses at once?  Or is it a property that you set?

Any help here would be great.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could accomplish both with something like this:

```
private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Control)
    {
        listView1.MultiSelect = true;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, I knew it was going to be something ridiculously easy.  Thanks.

Comment: I had the problem when using CTRL+A the listbox would jump to the first "A" item after selecting all. (Leaving only one item selected.) Adding `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` after the loop solved this.

Comment: For large lists, one should suspend update.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/15398091/340790

Comment: In 2022 with VS2022 this still works. Thanks!

Comment: `e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Control` didn't work for me, it cought event on the second pressing of the keys (I don't know why), but the condition listed below worked fine: `e.KeyData == (Keys.A | Keys.Control)`

Answer (score 26):

These works for small lists, but if there are 100,000 items in a virtual list, this could take a long time. This is probably overkill for your purposes, but just in case::

```
class NativeMethods {
    private const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    private const int LVM_SETITEMSTATE = LVM_FIRST + 43;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct LVITEM
    {
        public int mask;
        public int iItem;
        public int iSubItem;
        public int state;
        public int stateMask;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string pszText;
        public int cchTextMax;
        public int iImage;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public int iIndent;
        public int iGroupId;
        public int cColumns;
        public IntPtr puColumns;
    };

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageLVItem(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, ref LVITEM lvi);

    /// <summary>
    /// Select all rows on the given listview
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">The listview whose items are to be selected</param>
    public static void SelectAllItems(ListView list) {
        NativeMethods.SetItemState(list, -1, 2, 2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deselect all rows on the given listview
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">The listview whose items are to be deselected</param>
    public static void DeselectAllItems(ListView list) {
        NativeMethods.SetItemState(list, -1, 2, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the item state on the given item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">The listview whose item's state is to be changed</param>
    /// <param name="itemIndex">The index of the item to be changed</param>
    /// <param name="mask">Which bits of the value are to be set?</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to be set</param>
    public static void SetItemState(ListView list, int itemIndex, int mask, int value) {
        LVITEM lvItem = new LVITEM();
        lvItem.stateMask = mask;
        lvItem.state = value;
        SendMessageLVItem(list.Handle, LVM_SETITEMSTATE, itemIndex, ref lvItem);
    }
}
```

and you use it like this::

```
NativeMethods.SelectAllItems(this.myListView);
```

Comment: Are there any prerequisites to getting this code to run? I'm trying it on a regular .NET ListView with CheckBoxes = true. And it's not doing anything.

Comment: can you provide vb.net version

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great! I use a listview in virtual mode. But somehow the number of items seems to be limited. Are you sure 100.000 rows are possible?

Comment: There is an upper limit of 9,999,999. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2462211/106008

Comment: Is there a version of this that works with setting the "checked" state of every list view item for a "check all" and "uncheck all" scenario?

Comment: You don't need to implement deselect yourself; there's a built-in `SelectedIndices.Clear()` method. Internally it does the same thing as this.

Comment: This is amazing. In a ListView with 143k entries the time to select all items with this method compared to the foreach method went down from 69 s to 0.3 s.

Answer (score 7):

```
private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.A | Keys.Control))
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            item.Selected = true;
}
```

To *only* do it on Ctrl+A, not on other combinations like Ctrl+Shift+A etc.

Comment: +1 for point "To only do it on Ctrl+A", Grammarian's solution is better for performance though

Comment: For large lists, one should suspend update.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/15398091/340790

Answer (score 3):

The first solution won't work if user releases the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key first.

You should use the `KeyDown` event instead:

```
private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Control)
    {
        listView1.MultiSelect = true;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not able to post a comment on first answer so I posted a new answer (sorry about that)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be any different from the first answer (except the order of chcks in the if statement). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment on the first question, however solution with KeyDown does not work for me, because system immediately reacts on LeftCtrl pressed and so skips CTRL+A. From other side KeyUp works correctly.

```
private void listView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Control)
    {
        listView1.MultiSelect = true;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```