# C# ListView SelectAll selection color

Tags: c#, listview, select

I am trying to set all items of a ListView as selected, using

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in this.m_lvFiles.Items)
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
```

and this works. However the listbox looks as 
[Select All, programatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hkXy.png) (all items' background color is white).
If I select the items manually, the background color is blue, as in the second image ([Select All, manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv3Re.png)).

```
HideSelection=False, FullRowSelection=True, MultiSelect=True.
```

Question: is there a way to bring programmatically selected items like if they were selected manually?

Or is there a bug in ListView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on where the focus is for your application, the selection may not show up as "blue". Setting the focus back to the list view after selecting each item will make each item's background 'blue':

```
m_lvFiles.Focus();
```

Assuming this is a win forms app...

Comment: Thank you denvercoder9, this IS a win forms app, but just calling Focus() does not seem to help (I would not have asked otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

There is a related question about it that might help you:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019388/adding-a-select-all-shortcut-ctrl-a-to-a-net-listview)

```
public static void SetItemState(ListView list, int itemIndex, int mask, int value) {
    LVITEM lvItem = new LVITEM();
    lvItem.stateMask = mask;
    lvItem.state = value;
    SendMessageLVItem(list.Handle, LVM_SETITEMSTATE, itemIndex, ref lvItem);
}
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks Nestoraj, can you please specify how to use this function? 
What values should 'mask' and 'value' have? 
A code snippet would be best.